# process data for new clients into data warehosue

Tags: mysql, database, etl, data-warehouse

we have a data warehouse we are processing incremental data for various clients on srvtimestamp based.currently we have open new clients with previous or historical transaction in OLTP i need to process data for New clients from day one .I need a dyanamic process which every time check the new clients and their srvtimestamp also to process data.

we are using Mysql Storedprocedures to incremental data loading which select max (srvtimestamp) from table and load data based on srvtimestamp

Answer (score 0):

You should use case statement in select like below.

```
select case new_client_flag = 'New' then  min(srvtimestamp) else max(srvtimestamp) end as 'srvtimestamp'
from table
```

you should use flag for `new_client_flag` and update it after first processing if

```
new_client_flag = 'NEW'
```